# Setting UI orientation manually on iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm having some trouble with user interface orientation in view controller on iOS 6. Basically, I have one view controller which supports both portrait and landscape modes. This of course works with no issues, but I also need to implement the button which will toggle between landscape and portrait modes when pressed - without user rotating the device. I basically need the same behavior as video player in youtube application.

I have tried to use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:animated:]
```

Problem is, that this works fine only on iOS 5. On iOS 6, this function does not work until I implement:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return 0;
}
```

And here comes the issue... When I return 0 in the mask, view controller's view is not auto-rotating the content (of course) and the only way is to rotate it manually, like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
...

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation;
    switch (deviceOrientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            break;
        default:
            interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            break;
    }
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation != interfaceOrientation)
        [self layoutForInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

...

- (void)layoutForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:orientation animated:YES];

    CGFloat angle = 0.0f;
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            angle = 0.0f;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            angle = -M_PI / 2;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            angle = M_PI / 2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^(void){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:orientation  animated:NO];
        [self.view setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];

    }];
...
```

This solution seems really dirty to me. Is there any simpler way how to achieve the toggling of landscape / portrait modes using button on iOS 6?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration try this mehod